# Pango-1.40.1: Error while compiling on Wind River Linux

Tags: linux, iot, pango

I am trying to install gtk-2+xx on Wind River Linux. I have installed below dependencies in term to install gtk.
Glib-2.48.1
atk-2.20.0
Cairo-1.14.6
I have put all the related *.pc to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. I am trying to install Pango-1.40.1 which is one of the dependency for gtk.
./configure for pango done successfully. Please see the result below.

```
checking for HARFBUZZ... yes // found HARFBUZZ
checking for FONTCONFIG... yes // found FONTCONFIG
checking for FcWeightFromOpenType... no
checking for FREETYPE... yes // found FREETYPE
checking for XFT... no
checking for CoreText availability... no
checking for CAIRO... yes*
checking which cairo font backends could be used... freetype
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for LIBTHAI... no
checking for gobject-introspection... no
checking for flockfile... yes
checking for strtok_r... yes

    configuration:
            backends: Cairo FreeType // Configured with Cairo's font backend of type FreeType
```

But "make" is giving error. Below is the snippet of the error received. The same error is repeated in different lines of the source code of frimini.c file.

```
fribidi.c:73:24: error: expected expression before 'TypeLink'
   link = g_slice_new0 (TypeLink);
```

I am enable to resolve this.So if someone can advice how to resolve this issue or any other dependency is need to be installed, will help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I myself resoled the problem. source code versions of Pango and Glib has to be compatible with each other. I was using Glib-2.48 with Pango-1.40. I changed it with compatible set of these two packages(Glib-2.40 and Pango-1.15) and resolved the issue.